# an equality in module theory

Tags: modules

Let $R$ be a ring and $M$ be an $R$-module. Let $N$ and $L$ be two submodules of $M$ such that
$(rad(N+L):M)=\sqrt{(N:M)+(L:M)}$. Then can we conclude that $(N+L:M)=(N:M)+(L:M)$?
Note that $(N:M)=\{r\in R: rM\subseteq N\}$ and $rad(N)$ is the intersection of all prime sumodules of $M$ containing $N$.